# Writing to .json.gz file using jackson object mapper

Tags: json, jackson

I need to create a .json.gz file using an ArrayList

```
void func(ArrayList<AirConfig> configList)
{
  String filePath = "abc.json.gz";
  File file = new File(filePath);

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.writeValue(file, configList);
}
```

This however dosent really work because when I try to unzip the file using the following command

```
gzip -cd configMasterAirport_Test.json.gz > configMasterAirport_Test.json
```

I get the following error,

```
abc.json.gz: not in gzip format
```

How do I rewrite my code so that the a compressed json is generated but I'm still able to use the Object Mapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You require only a small change.

```
void func(ArrayList<AirConfig> configList)
{
   FileOutputStream fStream = null;
   GZIPOutputStream zStream = null;

   try
   {
      String filePath = "abc.json.gz";
      fStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
      zStream = new GZIPOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fStream));

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(zStream, configList);
   }
   finally
   {
      if (zStream != null)
      {
        zStream.flush();
        zStream.close();
      }
      if (fStream != null)
      {
        fStream.flush();
        fStream.close();
      }
   }
}
```